# Ampache install page not displaying correctly

Tags: php, apache2

Having installed Ampache into my Apache server, I navigated to localhost/ampache/install.php.

However, the page didn't display correctly on any devices.

It's supposed to look like this apparently:

[How it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhXPF.png)

The page on my server looks like this:

[How it's probably not supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78lSa.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple.
This is because your PHP port is being used by another service on your system.
Open your task manager and navigate to the services tab.
Search for world wide web services and stop it.
Now refresh your WAMP and the WAMP icon should turn green within a few seconds.
Open the link again and success!!!

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like that the file ampache.cfg.php isn't writable.

Go to the file (Localted at /usr/share/ampache/www/config/ampache.cfg.php and see what the rights tot the file is. If the file exists and there is no write rights for it, then simply change it using chmod.

The user that needs the write-rights are called www-data or apache.

Assuming it's apache run the following:

```
chgrp -Rv apache /usr/share/ampache/www/config/ampache.cfg.php
chmod g=rwx -R /usr/share/ampache/www/config/ampache.cfg.php
```

That will give apache ownership of the group, and give the group read/write/execute rights to that file.

Either that, or maybe you don't have MySQL server installed (Or perhaps a user in MySQL with the appropriate rights/permissions).

Also the config file (ampache.cfg.php), needs to have the right information in it, with server, username and password.

Comment: What user should have write permission?

Comment: @Nectar I believe it's called www-data or apache.

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't solved the problem. The ERROR has turned to OK, that's all. The page still looks to same :/

Comment: @Nectar It would then seem like it could be your MySQL setup. Do you have an MySQL server installed, and a user setup?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do I need to tell Ampache any of this?

Comment: @Nectar yes you should edit the ampache.cfg.php file, and specify the right values.

Comment: Hmm. Nano recognises the file as empty, and ls lists it fine :/

Comment: The point of the install page is to create this file, so writing to it would defeat the object. I need to get the page to display correctly, which can only be either ampache's, apache2's, or php7's.

Comment: @Nectar to my knowledge you need to tell ampache, what user, server and password to use. This should be in the config file.

Comment: The config file is empty, so I can't fill anything in.

Comment: chmod g=rwx -R /usr/share/ampache/www/config/ampache.cfg.php - This doesn't work, because the file is a 'dangling symlink'